# javascript equivalent of jquery all children selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery selector which I am trying to convert to regular javascript.

```
$("#lelement>*").on("dblclick", function(){
});
```

what would the equivalent be with regular javascript ?
Can I do this ?

```
document.getElementById('element').childNodes.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant, non-jQuery way to do this would be via  `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('#lelement > *').forEach(function(node) {
        node.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
           console.log('double clicked on child of #element');
        });
    })
```

```css
p {
margin:1rem;
background:red;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="lelement">
<p>Double click me - Child 1</p>
<p>Double click me - Child 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to explicitly iterate over all elements which match the `#lelement>*` selector (the collection can be obtained with `querySelectorAll`), and then attach a handler to each of them:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#lelement > *').forEach((child) => {
  child.addEventListener('dblclick', () => console.log('double clicked!'));
});
```

```html
<div id="lelement">
  <div>content 1</div>
  <div>content 2</div>
</div>
```

Note that `NodeList.forEach` isn't all that old a method; not all browsers support it. So, for ancient browsers, use a polyfill or `Array.prototype.forEach` instead:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#lelement > *'),
  (child) => {
    child.addEventListener('dblclick', () => console.log('double clicked!'));
  }
);
```

```html
<div id="lelement">
  <div>content 1</div>
  <div>content 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be the exact same selector, just passed to [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
document.querySelectorAll("#element > *");
```

Then, you would enumerate the found nodes and manually set each up with an event handler. Since `.querySelectorAll()` returns a node list, it's best to convert that to an `Array` so that the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method can be reliably called in all browsers.

```js
let elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#element > *"));

elems.forEach((el) => { el.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
  console.log("You clicked me!");
}); });
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  <div>Some Div</div>
</div>
```